# python openpyxl load_workbook list indices error

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am executing the below python 2.7.12 script and am getting the **"list indices must be integers, not NoneType"** error. I am getting this error only for few excel books. Excel format is .xlsx. No .xls files. Can someone please help me in this regard.

```
try:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(wbpath, read_only=True)
    wrkshts = wb.get_sheet_names()
except Exception, err:
    wrkshts=[]
    sys.stderr.write('ERROR: %s\n' % str(err)) 
return wrkshts
```

Comment: what is wbpath ? does that include Excel File name as well ?

Comment: yes. it includes the excel file name as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue using the "Read an existing workbook" code from the "simple usage" section of the openpyxl docs.  After doing some debugging in openpyxl code, I  found that I had a bunch of named ranges in my workbook with #Ref! values.  I deleted all of the named ranges as they all seemed leftover and not part of the workbook.  This fixed the problem.  However, I didn't get to test if deleting / correcting ONLY the REF error named ranges would fix it.  Maybe you can try that and leave a comment.

Comment: Deleting ONLY the REF error named ranges fixed the issue!